# Como passar o sinal de "+" usando GET?

Tags: html, http, url, get

Preciso enviar um parâmetro **GET** que está criptografado em **AES** porém na hash as vezes vem um `+` e no envio o navegador interpreta esse `+` separando a hash.

**Exemplo da URL:**

```
http://meusite/rota/?empresa=U2FsdGVkX1+T0MCaQbe7CRkz6jsZQoznI80UCEK6s0I=
```

**Como recebo o parâmetro empresa:**

```
U2FsdGVkX1 T0MCaQbe7CRkz6jsZQoznI80UCEK6s0I=
```

como posso tratar esse GET para receber a hash sem separação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque o sinal de `+` por `%2B`, se estiver gerando o link via JavaScript pode fazer assim:

```js
var resultado = encodeURIComponent("U2FsdGVkX1+T0MCaQbe7CRkz6jsZQoznI80UCEK6s0I=");

console.log(resultado);
```

Se estiver gerando via PHP pode fazer assim:

```
<a href="foo/?empresa=<?php echo rawurlencode('U2FsdGVkX1+T0MCaQbe7CRkz6jsZQoznI80UCEK6s0I='); ?>">link</a>
```

Em HTML basicamente seria isso:

```
<a href="foo/?empresa=U2FsdGVkX1%2BT0MCaQbe7CRkz6jsZQoznI80UCEK6s0I=">link</a>
```